Equivariant Maps for a Simply Transitive Group Action
As described in my answer to this post, if $G$ acts simply transitively on $X$, we can completely characterize all equivariant maps $f: X \to X$.
I define $h : X \times X \to G$ such that $h(x,x')$ is the unique group element satisfying $h(x,x')x = x'$.
Given this definition, we then have that any equivariant map $f : X \to X$ can be written $f(x) = h(x_0, x)f(x_0)$, where $x_0 \in X$ is just some fixed "reference point."
My question is how one should think about such maps. My first guess would be that they're just translations, but this turns out to be false as one can easily check. If $f(x) = gx$ for some $g\in G$, then $f(hx) = hf(x)$ only if $g$ commutes with $h$.
So what are the equivariant maps doing? In my own words, it's like $f$ translates in the image by an amount proportional to how far away the points are in the domain. Is there more to say?

I don't think language of distance or proportionality helps much in this setting. There are no numbers in sight at all, no concept of distance. You have to grapple directly with the group theory.

Point taken, but in the commutative case we can simply say that the maps are translations. Is there language that is typically used in the noncommutative case for maps like $f(x) = h(x_0, x)f(x_0)$?

Perhaps more pointedly, we get an almost canonical bijection between such maps and $X$, but not $G$ unless $G$ is commutative. What's going on when $G$ isn't commutative? It seems strange, especially since $X$ is just $G$ where we forget the identity.

I suggest exploiting the fact that any simply transitive action of $G$ on a set $X$ is conjugate to the left multiplication action of $G$ on itself: $h(\gamma,\delta)=\gamma\delta$ for all $\gamma,\delta \in G$. Whatever solution you find for that special case can then be transported over to $X$ using the conjugating map.

One more thing one can say is that we only need a simply transitive action on the domain to get this kind of simple description.
More explicitly, let $X$ be simply transitive and $Y$ be any $G$-set and fix $x_0 \in X$, then we have a bijection: $$\mathrm{Hom}_{G\textrm{-}\mathbf{Set}}(X,Y) \xrightarrow{\cong} Y, f \mapsto f(x_0)$$
In terms of category theory, this bijection is natural, which means that any simply transitive $G$-set represents the forgetful functor $G\textrm{-}\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$.
Again to phrase this differently in terms of category theory, this means that a simply transitive $G$-set is a free $G$-set on one object. Thus on a categorical level, this kind of description is similar to the natural bijections $\mathrm{Hom}_{k\textrm{-}\mathbf{Vect}}(k,V)\cong V$ for any $k$ vector space $V$ or $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Grp}}(\Bbb Z,G)\cong G$ for any group $G$.
Actually if we allow ourselves to use an isomorphism $X \cong G$ as $G$-sets, then the bijection $\mathrm{Hom}_{G\textrm{-}\mathbf{Set}}(G,Y)\cong Y$ looks a lot like the familiar bijection from linear algebra: For $\mathrm{Hom}_{k\textrm{-}\mathbf{Vect}}(k,V)\cong V$ we have mutually inverse bijections $f \mapsto f(1)$ and $v \mapsto (\lambda \mapsto \lambda v)$. Similarly, we have mutually inverse bijections $\mathrm{Hom}_{G\textrm{-}\mathbf{Set}}(G,Y)\cong Y$ given by $f \mapsto f(1)$ and $y \mapsto (g \mapsto gy)$
